# How to create instance from already uploaded VMDK image at S3 bucket

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, openstack

I have already uploaded my VMDK file to the S3 bucket using following command:

`s3cmd put /root/Desktop/centos-ldaprad.vmdk --multipart-chunk-size-mb=10 s3://xxxxx`

Now When I would like to create AWS Instance from the same VMDK available at S3 bucket:

`ec2-import-instance centos-ldaprad.vmdk -f VMDK -t t2.micro -a x86_64 -b xxxxx -o <XXXX_ACCESS_KEY_XXXX> -w <XXXX_SECRET_KEY_XXX> -p Linux --dont-verify-format -s 5 --ignore-region-affinity`

But It looks on present working directory for the source VMDK file. I will be really greatful if you can guide to how to point source VMDK at bucket instead of local source?

Does this `--manifest-url url` points to the S3 bucket? But when I have uploaded do not have any idea whether it has created any such file? If it creates where it would be created?

Another thing is using above `ec2-import-instance` when I am creating it searches for VMDK on present working directory and if found it will start uploading. But is there any provision to make upload in parts and also to resume in case of interruption?

Comment: `ec2-resume-import` can help to resume the interrupted upload using `ec2-import-instance`, right?

Comment: You could always mount the s3 bucket and run the command as if it was local.  The manifest URL should work, but I belive you have to convert the VMDK before you upload it to a AMI.

Comment: Dave thanks for your reply! But I haven't converted my VMDK. Using above command I have uploaded in a multipart. And after that when I am creating Instance using `ec2-import-instance` it is raising an error. But when my command prompt is in the directory where this VMDK is available it stars uploading. I have used `ec2-import-instance` command.

Comment: When I mount S3 bucket on a local file system, my bucket is loosing all the features of AWS like speed. So instead of mounting, is there any other way by which I can directly access VMDK file uploaded in S3 bucket.

Comment: I have mounted S3 bucket to AWS instance, and made s3 bucket direcoty `PWD`. but still when I am firing `ec2-important-instance` command in above syntaxt it is uploading `VMDK` again to the given bucket name. My main concern is `VMDK` is already uploaded to the S3 bucket and then how to create instance from there?

Answer (score 0):

It's not really the answer you were after, but I've attached the script I use to upload VMDKs and convert them to AMI images.

This uses the ec2-resume-import, so you can restart it if a upload partially fails.

http://pastebin.com/bD8c3gQu

It's worth pointing out that when I register the device I specify a block device mapping.  This is because my images always include a separate boot partition, and a LVM based root partition.

--root-device-name /dev/sda1 -b /dev/sda=$SNAPSHOT_ID:10:true --region $REGION -a x86_64 --kernel aki-52a34525

Comment: When I mount S3 bucket on a local file system, my bucket is loosing all the features of AWS like speed. So instead of mounting, is there any other way by which I can directly access VMDK file uploaded in S3 bucket.

Comment: Yeah on second thoughts its not such a good idea, as the local application will be reading the data across the network.  Doing it from an instance within AWS would be slightly faster.

Comment: Thanks Dave! Another thing I would like to know, is there any parameter such as multipart with `ec2-import-instance` the way we are using with `s3cmd`?

Comment: I have mounted S3 bucket to AWS instance, and made s3 bucket directory PWD. but still when I am firing ec2-important-instance command in above syntax it is uploading VMDK again to the given bucket name. My main concern is VMDK is already uploaded to the S3 bucket and then how to create instance from there?

Comment: Hi so it's the default behaviour that it will always upload the content itself.  I can't quiet remember but I'm pretty sure AWS does the conversion and breaks up the image into multiple parts so you don't see the complete VMDK uploaded.

Comment: Is there any way to skip uploading and directly use `VMDK` from S3 bucket?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.

Comment: Hi @Dave, after you created AMI from the snapshot, were you able to start launch EC2 instance from it ?